# Comparing and Contrasting Python's many Image Processing Libraries

Tags: python, image-processing, package

I'm a bit mystified as to why Python has so many imaging packages implemented and have been trying to find a table comparing and contrasting either features, strengths/weaknesses, speed/performance, application areas, etc between the bunch of them. So far I know of PIL, mahotas, scikits.image, and scipy.ndimage. I suppose we could also include the many bindings that are supported by external libraries such as ImageMagic, OpenCV, Cairo, etc but let's just start with stuff written specifically for Python. Does anyone know first hand, or is familiar with a blog post or some central location where all these packages are compared and distinguished from one another.

Comment: Questions like these belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I help maintain a page on the [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) wiki comparing 20 or so common image processing libraries for speed and memory use, including quite a few Python systems.

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use

The benchmark is very simple: load a 5,000 x 5,000 pixel RGB TIFF, crop 100 pixels from each edge, shrink 10%, sharpen with a 3x3 convolution, and save again. It's a silly test, but simple to implement and it does exercise convolution, load/save, resample and pixel manipulation.

The test is on the libvips wiki, so of course libvips (and [pyvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/), the Python binding) wins, but the results are a reasonable guide, at least for simple tasks like this, in my experience. It's also fun to [compare the code](https://github.com/libvips/vips-bench).

```
System                    | Run time (secs) | Peak mem use (MB)
---------------------------------------------------------------
libvips C 8.8             | 0.15            |  40 
pyvips 2.1.6              | 0.18            |  49 
Pillow-SIMD 5.3           | 0.36            | 230 
NetPBM 10.0-15.3          | 0.60            |  75 
sips 10.4.4               | 0.70            | 268 
GraphicsMagick 1.3.28     | 0.64            | 493 
ImageMagick 6.9.7-4       | 0.82            | 463 
OpenCV 3.2                | 0.93            | 222 
ImageMagick 7.0.8         | 1.37            | 733 
ImageJ 1.51               | 2.84            | 770 
scipy 1.2 + Pillow        | 4.33            | 361
```

Here's the same thing graphically:

[image: graph speed mem use]

Comment: Just curious where Python Wand fits in your list.

Comment: Hey Fred, I'd guess pretty close to IM, but I've not tested it directly. Please do open a PR if you know how to implement this in Wand.

Comment: Hello John, I will try to make a Python Wand script for you and send in a request. Thanks.

Comment: Updated, thanks cgohike. I'll update the wiki too. Thanks Fred, it'd be interesting to add. I should re-run the tests for ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 2):

I have used mahotas extensively, but currently switched to scikit-image. I found scikit-image a bit more extensive in its functionality than mahotas (I need to test various image processing algoorithms frequently). Mahotas main advantage is simple codes with good documentation, which is is agreement with its [mahotas-principles](http://mahotas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/principles.html#principles-of-mahotas/). So, if you require basic functions and faster operation, go for Mahotas. I haven't done a detailed study of scipy-nd image, but looking at the list of available functions, skimage would have the upperhand.